# How to raise onClick/Change event in kendogrid using angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I have built a grid using kendogrid wrapped-up with angular2. the grid is getting populated with records by consuming the webapi service. I need to raise a rowclick event on the grid and on the click event, I need to fetch the record/async call to get the details for the row/record selected and display below on details section the same page. The details sections consists of around 10-12 textbox and I should be able to bind the values fetched from the services call.

In My UI, I have a grid in the top section - the grid is loaded with some record by consuming the services. When the user click on a any single row, the below details section controls to be loaded with the details values fetched by the asynch call.

any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I tried the below way to raise the event, but it is not working.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Grid } from './grid';

declare var kendo: any;
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'kendo-grid',
    template: `<div>
                    <k-grid [options]="options" (change)="onClick($event)"></k-grid>
                </div>`,
    providers: [Configuration, Constants],
    directives: [Grid]
})
export class ExtractorGrid {

    options: any;
    rowObject: any;
    extractorDetails: any;
    public component: any;
    queueID: number;

    constructor(private configSetttings: Configuration, private constants: Constants, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private _cr: ComponentResolver) {
        this.setUpGridOptions();
    }

    onClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("click event called");
    }
}
```

grid.ts where k-grid is defined

```
import { Component, Input, Host, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'k-grid',
    template: '<div></div>'
})

export class Grid implements OnInit {
    constructor( @Host() private elm: ElementRef) {
        console.log("in constructor of Grid");
    }

    selectedRow: any;

    @Input() options: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("in OnInit of Grid");
        $(this.elm.nativeElement).children().first().kendoGrid(this.options);
        console.log("after assigning to to kendo");



    }
}
```

Comment: Well, we don't know, how `k-grid` is set up - maybe post `grid.ts` too.

Comment: added grid.ts - k-grid is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I need to assign the click event while generating the kendogrid along with the selector.

In HTML template

```
<div>
    <k-grid [options]="options" (click)="onChange($event)"></k-grid>
</div>
```

In the kendogrid generator component,

```
 this.options = {
            dataSource: dataSource,
            columns: [
....
],
  ],
            pageable: true,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true,
            click: "onChange",
}
```

OnChange event function

```
 onChange(event) {
        console.log("click event called");
        console.log("event " + event);
        event.preventDefault();

...
}
```